# Active link border/underline

Tags: css

I would like to put an underline on the active icon link. I am able to underline but it is too close to the icon but I want to underline at the bottom-top of the navigation bar as shown in the image below.

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 75);
}

.header__left>img {
  height: 40px;
}

.header__center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 52px;
}

.header__right {
  display: flex;
}

.header__info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.header__info>span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.header__option.active>i {
  color: #1877f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.header__option:hover {
  background-color: #f0f2f5;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Free_logo.svg/600px-Free_logo.svg.png" />

  </div>
  <div class="header__center">
    <div class="header__option active">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <div class="header__info">
      <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg"></i>
      <span class="header__info__name">Aakash</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the way of underlining the icon with the exact width that is taken while hovering over the icons?

Comment: you need to apply the border on the parent element of the icon 
```.header__option.active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
} ```

Comment: Then just remove the `padding` from the `.header` element and add more `height` on the `.header__option` element.

Comment: can you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the border on the parent element of the icon

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px 20px 0px 20px; /* was padding: 15px 20px */
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 75);
}
/* added below four lines for image centering */
.header__left {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.header__left>img {
  height: 40px;
}

.header__center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 52px;
}

.header__right {
  display: flex;
}

.header__info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.header__info>span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
/* added below four lines for bottom border on active link */
.header__option.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
}

.header__option.active>i {
  color: #1877f2;
  /* removed border-bottom, border-bottom-width and bottom rules */
}

.header__option:hover {
  background-color: #f0f2f5;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Free_logo.svg/600px-Free_logo.svg.png" />

  </div>
  <div class="header__center d-none d-xl-flex d-md-flex">
    <div class="header__option active">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <div class="header__info d-none d-xl-flex">
      <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg"></i>
      <span class="header__info__name">Aakash</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @aakash I also centered the image because it went up as we removed the `padding-top` is `0`

Comment: can you comment on the css that what you have added and what you removed?

Comment: sure thing, comments added.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use pseudo elements (::after & ::before) for active states and for the underline.

```
.header__option{
position: relative;
}
.header__option.active::after{
content:'';
position: absolute;
bottom: -10px; (set it accordingly)
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 1px;
background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px 20px 0;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 75);
}

.header__left>img {
  height: 40px;
}

.header__center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 52px;
}

.header__right {
  display: flex;
}

.header__info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.header__info>span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.header__option.active {
  color: #1877f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
}

.header__option:hover {
  background-color: #f0f2f5;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Free_logo.svg/600px-Free_logo.svg.png" />

  </div>
  <div class="header__center d-none d-xl-flex d-md-flex">
    <div class="header__option active">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <div class="header__info d-none d-xl-flex">
      <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg"></i>
      <span class="header__info__name">Aakash</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you added..what you remove? can you explain?

Comment: I changed the header padding from `padding: 15px 20px` to `padding: 15px 20px 0` and also changed `.header__option.active>i` to `.header__option.active`

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working example:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 75);
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.header__left>img {
  height: 40px;
}

.header__left .header__option, .header__right .header__option, .header__center .header__option {
  height: 60px;
  min-width: 60px;
}

.header__center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__right {
  display: flex;
}

.header__info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.header__info>span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.header__option.active, .header__option.active:hover {
  color: #1877f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
}

.header__option:hover {
  background-color: #f0f2f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Free_logo.svg/600px-Free_logo.svg.png" />

  </div>
  <div class="header__center">
    <div class="header__option active">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <div class="header__info d-none d-xl-flex">
      <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg"></i>
      <span class="header__info__name">Aakash</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why the border is hiding in hover? can the hover be removed if the class is active?

Comment: Oh, just need to change hover color to `red` when hovering `header__option.active: hover'. let me update the example.

Comment: the solution to underline is to add just the width....right?

Comment: @aakash No, I have done some changes in your style to do this, I have removed padding from the `.header` class & given a fixed `height` & `min-width` to  `.header__option` class to adopt full height, so that the border will always be on bottom of the header.

Comment: @aakash I have added `min-width` to make it looks little wider.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220722/discussion-between-yogendra-chauhan-and-aakash).