# Active link border/underline over a bootstrap navbar class

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to adapt the solution from the question [Active link border/underline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63666874/active-link-border-underline) asked by me.

I tried to adopt the same solution in the bootstrap `navbar` but there are some other effects with that solution.

Like I changed the padding of `nav.navbar` to `15px 20px 0px`, the actual problem was solved whereas the `hover` and the `alignment of the icon` moved slightly down from the center.

```
nav.navbar {
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 20px 0px;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 75);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav.navbar {
  padding: 15px 20px 0px;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 75);
}

.header__left>img {
  height: 40px;
}

.header__items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #e4e6eb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}

.header__center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 52px;
}

.header__right {
  display: flex;
}

.header__info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.header__info>span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.header__option:hover {
  background-color: #f0f2f5;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}

.header__option.active,
.header__option.active:hover {
  color: #1877f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1877f2;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">

  <div class="header__left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Free_logo.svg/600px-Free_logo.svg.png" />

  </div>
  <div class="header__center">
    <div class="header__option active">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <div class="header__info">
      <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg"></i>
      <span class="header__info__name">Aakash</span>
    </div>
    <div class="header__items">
      <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__items">
      <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__items">
      <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The effect I wanted to have while hovering the icon.
[image]

Updated questions to reflect what I also want:
[image]

Comment: do you want space under the icon when hovering?

Comment: yes i want the space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a "fake" bottom border same color as the background of navbar to the icons.

Like so -

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav.navbar {
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px; /* REMOVED TOP PADDING */
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 75);
}

.header__left>img {
  height: 40px;
}

.header__center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 52px;
  /* REMOVED BORDER */
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid #f8f9fa;*/ /* the fake border */
  /*border-bottom-width: 3px;*/ /* fake border width */
  
  /* ADDED BOX SHADOW */
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px #f8f9fa;
}

.header__right {
  display: flex;
}

.header__info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.header__info>span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.header__option:hover {
  background-color: #f0f2f5;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}

.header__option.active,
.header__option.active:hover {
  color: #1877f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1877f2;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">

  <div class="header__left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Free_logo.svg/600px-Free_logo.svg.png" />

  </div>
  <div class="header__center">
    <div class="header__option active">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <div class="header__info">
      <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg"></i>
      <span class="header__info__name">Aakash</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Update:** Changed `border-bottom` in `header_options` property to `box-shadow.`

**2nd Update:** removed top padding from `nav.navbar` to vertically center icons.

Comment: this solves the problem of spacing below the icons but another problem here is that now the icons are not aligning in the middle, they are not slightly shifted to down. you can see more on my updated questions with extra icon on the class `header__right`

Comment: Ok.. then you can use `box-shadow` instead of `border` as @bertdida suggested. I'll update my answer.

Comment: you are considering only one part of the problem, there is another problem with the padding on `nav.navbar`, that I have shown in the questions.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I have removed the top padding from `nav.navbar` to make icons vertically center.

Answer (score 0):

You could use inner `box-shadow`.

```css
.header__option.active,
.header__option:hover {
  color: #1877f2;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px #1877f2;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #1877f2; */
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
}
```

```css
nav.navbar {
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 20px 0px;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 75);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav.navbar {
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 20px 0px;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 75);
}

.header__left>img {
  height: 40px;
}

.header__items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #e4e6eb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}

.header__center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 52px;
}

.header__right {
  display: flex;
}

.header__info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.header__info>span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.header__option:hover {
  background-color: #f0f2f5;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}

.header__option.active,
.header__option:hover {
  color: #1877f2;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px #1877f2;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #1877f2; */
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="header__left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Free_logo.svg/600px-Free_logo.svg.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="header__center">
    <div class="header__option active">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="header__option">
      <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <div class="header__info">
      <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg"></i>
      <span class="header__info__name">Aakash</span>
    </div>
    <div class="header__items">
      <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I want the space after the icon while hover and, the icons and all the icons are also not aligning in the middle, the got moved to down.

Comment: no not the border while hover. only the background effect.

Comment: Ohhh. I misunderstood sorry, maybe @Debsmita's answer is what you need.